# Can I Use Winsock To Construct And Send ARP Packets, Or Receive ARP Packets? How?

Tags: winsock, arp

I was try on WINDOWS XP(but this is not the point), while I thought I cannot send or receive ARP packets with Raw Winsock, but some paper from Internet says yes, if so, how to set the Winsock functions?

Comment: It would help if you could include a link to the paper on the Internet that you refer to in your question.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post however it's worth mentioning that there is a Win32 API call for sending ARP requests:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this makes sense.  I would think ARP is a link layer protocol and requests are generated at network stack (if not NIC) level.